# c# switch all letters in a string for a different pre-chosen letter

Tags: c#, string, cryptography

Whilst working on a simple project I was trying to come up with a very basic cryptographic system which will allow me to switch letters in a message to another pre-chosen letter. So far I have tried a few ways but have so far been unsuccessful in my attempts. (*NOTE: This is not for anything other then learning the basics of c# so randomness and security is not important in this case, I simply want to turn one letter into another for the sake of learning how to do it)

so first I started by defining some strings such as this

```
string a = "a";
string b = "b";
string c = "d";
..... //continues to string z = "z"
```

next I tried to create a new string based on the values that have been input in to a textbox called `PlainTextBox` and place them inside a separate textbox called `ChangedTextBox`. this code is triggered with a button click event.

```
string str = PlainTextBox.Text;
char[] array = str.ToCharArray();
array[int.Parse(a)] = 'x';
array[int.Parse(b)] = 'y';
array[int.Parse(c)] = 'z';
.......// continues to (z)
str = new string(array);
ChangedTextBox.Text = str;
```

but this code throws an exception because the input is not a valid integer. the basic Idea is that if the user types "abc" in the `PlainTextBox` and pushes a button, the `ChangedTextBox` should show "xyz" but should be inclusive of the whole text in PlainTextBox, switching every letter in the message to its chosen counterpart.

Besides the error I receive, this code seems very cumbersome and inefficient.

Is there a faster way to achieve this result?

Comment: Use a char rather than string `(int)'a'` is 97, b is 98 and so on, offset from there.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As "a" is a string, you cant convert (or parse) it as an int.

Comment: If the input string was "abcd", would the output be "xyza"?

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness I will also include information, that what you are doing is called [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

You could define yourself a proper `Dictionary`

```
var mapping = new Dictionary<char, char>()
{
    { 'a', 'x' },
    { 'b', 'y' },
    { 'c', 'z' }
    // other letters
}
```

in which you would assign every original letter the letter it should be converted to. Then you could use this dictionary

```
ChangedTextBox.Text = new string(PlainTextBox.Text.Select(letter => mapping[letter].ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you Pawel Hemperek, using a dictionary is definitely what I was looking for, I have managed to implement what I was trying to achieve thanks to your tip!

Answer (score 1):

You've chosen wrong collection type (*array*) for mapping; *dictionary* is much more convenient

```
private static Dictionary<char, char> m_Mapping = new Dictionary<char, char>() {
  {'a', 'x'}, // a -> x
  {'b', 'y'}, // b -> y
  ...  
};
```

Then implement the encoding

```
// I'd rather used Linq
private static String Encode(String value) {
  // Simplest: we don't check if the actual character can be mapped 
  return String.Concat(value.Select(c => m_Mapping[c]));
}
```

But your (amended) implementation is good enough:

```
private static String Encode(string str) {
  char[] array = str.ToCharArray();  

  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i) {
    // Simplest: we don't check if the actual character can be mapped 
    array[i] = m_Mapping[array[i]];
  }

  return new string(array);
}
```

Finally, add up UI:

```
ChangedTextBox.Text = Encode(PlainTextBox.Text);
```

**Edit:** in general case, when `m_Mapping` doesn't contain records for some characters (e.g. for *new line* `\n`) and so we want to preserve these characters intact we can't use direct `m_Mapping[...]` but should implement, say, `EncodeChar`.

```
private static char EncodeChar(char value) {
  char result;

  if (m_Mapping.TryGetValue(value, out result))
    return result;
  else
    return value;  
}
```

And put `EncodeChar(...)` instead of `m_Mapping[...]`

```
private static String Encode(String value) {
  return String.Concat(value.Select(EncodeChar(c)));
}
```

Your version

```
private static String Encode(string str) {
  char[] array = str.ToCharArray();  

  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i) {
    array[i] = EncodeChar(array[i]);

  return new string(array);
}
```

Comment: I would at least make an observation that the code should have the necessary error handling to cope with characters in the string that there is no mapping for. The solution as shown will throw a `KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Thank you! I see the point, it's actual esp. for *command symbols* like `\n`; often spaces ` ` aren't encoded as well in such cryptosystems.

Comment: wow thank you for the excellent explanation Dmitry, very helpful for my understanding of the Dictionary collection type which I knew nothing about.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best solution is using a Dictionary, as other answers had said. But if I understand what you want, you want to just change one letter by that letter plus an offset in a kind of "circular" way. This solution would do something like that (with "abcd" as input it would return "xyza"):

```
string input = "abcd";
char startChar = 'x';
char lastChar = 'z';
char firstChar = 'a';


byte[] asciiBytes=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
byte[] encriptedByteArray = new byte[asciiBytes.Length];

int val = (int)startChar-(int)firstChar;
int i = 0;
foreach(byte b in asciiBytes)
{
     var a=b + val;
     if (a>(int)lastChar)
     {
          a = firstChar+(a-lastChar)-1;
     }
     encriptedByteArray[i] = (byte)a;
     i++;
 }

 string encriptedArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encriptedByteArray);
```

With this solution you can change the offsety easily (changing `startChar`). It has room for improvement though, for example it only works on lower letters from a-z, it could be changed to be more extensive.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on using dictionaries and expanding on the code needed to achieve this, very helpful. 
this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
int.Parse(a)
```

will of course throw InvalidCastException because a is a string as you've defined it

```
string a = "a";
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the asked question

Comment: yes I noticed that this is the cause of the error because it is a string and not an integer as I defined, I'm sorry if my wording wasn't clear. I only included this code because I must provide sample code of previous attempts with my question to show what I have tried tried.
My question was asking what is the correct and most efficient way to achieve this.